# Nant - Check if a remote share already exists

Tags: windows, nant, psexec, fileshare

We are using Nant to deploy an application and need to ensure that a share is created during the process.

We use `psexec` and `net share` to create the share but this fails and stops Nant if the share already exists.

Is there any way to detect that a share exists already?

Either before trying to create the share or being able to detect the return code of `2` or the `The name has already been shared` message from `psexec`?

I have tried `directory::exists` but this always returns false.

I have tried copying a file to the remote dir and `file::exists` but this always returns false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears I am doing something wrong with my variables and paths:

```
<echo message="exists!" if="${directory::exists('\\${server}\share')}"/>
```

does not work, however:

```
<property name="test" value="\\${server}\share" />
<echo message="exists!" if="${directory::exists(test)}"/>
```

works fine!

Comment: You are doing something wrong with the variables. The function doesn't take ${} expressions, you just access the properties directly. Like `${directory::exists('\\' + server + '\share')}`.